# How to move the positioning of a link on an image in a navbar?

Tags: html, css

At the moment I have a navbar on my layout page which includes a logo. On this logo is a link to go to a website. However, the link only covers 10 pixels horizontally and 100 pixels vertically. I don't understand why.

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
                        <content class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-0" id="APTick">
                            <a href="http://www.google.co.uk/" class="navbar-brand" id="Logo">
                            </a>
                        </content>
                </div>
```

CSS:

```
#APTick{
    left: -15px;
    background-color: #698277;
}

#Logo {

    background-color: #698277;
    width: 100px;
    height: 72px;
    background-image: url("Images/Logo/ap_tick.png");
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
```

Can anybody help me move the positioning of the link space?

Answer (score 0):

`#Logo` is an inline element.
If you want to setup size you need to `display` it as `block` element

```css
#Logo {
    display:block;
    background-color: #698277;
    width: 100px;
    height: 72px;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("Images/Logo/ap_tick.png");
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-header">
                        <content class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-0" id="APTick">
                            <a href="http://www.google.co.uk/" class="navbar-brand" id="Logo">
                            </a>
                        </content>
                </div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I took your advice but this didn't change the positioning of the link. Do you know why?

Comment: What kind of position do you expect ? If you expect `left: -15px` you have to set `#APTick` as `position:absolute` or use a negative margin `margin-left:-15px`

Answer (score 0):

`<a>` element is inline element, so you cant set `height` on it, you can set `line-height` (not recomended) or make it `display:inline-block` or `display:block`